# List filled with last data instead of respecting insert order (Android)

Tags: java, android, list, mobile, xml-parsing

I have an XML parser that looks like this:

```
public class XMLParser {

public static void XMLParser(){

}

public List<itemRSS> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {
    String title = null;
    String link = null;
    String description = null;
    boolean isItem = false;
    List<itemRSS> items = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
        xmlPullParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        xmlPullParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

        xmlPullParser.nextTag();
        while (xmlPullParser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();

            String name = xmlPullParser.getName();
            if(name == null)
                continue;

            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    isItem = false;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    isItem = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            Log.d("MyXmlParser", "Parsing name ==> " + name);
            String result = "";
            if (xmlPullParser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = xmlPullParser.getText();
                xmlPullParser.nextTag();
            }

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                title = result;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                link = result;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                description = result;
            }

            if (title != null && link != null && description != null) {
                if(isItem) {
                    itemRSS item = new itemRSS(title, description, link);
                    items.add(item); 
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("leo: " + title);
                    //mFeedTitle = title;
                    //mFeedLink = link;
                   // mFeedDescription = description;
                }

                title = null;
                link = null;
                description = null;
                isItem = false;
            }
        }

        return items;
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}

}
```

This is my condition in the code which is not working properly

```
if (title != null && link != null && description != null) {
                if(isItem) {
                    itemRSS item = new itemRSS(title, description, link);
                    items.add(item); 
                }
```

Basically, Instead of adding to the list in the order {1,2,3,4}, it just looks like {4,4,4,4} when the execution finishes.

How can this happen? My intention is to do a simple RSS feed reader, so this parser is how I get the data from the feed to an Array, and then I set the Array as the adapter for a recycledView. Works fine so far, but it just writes a long list of the last title added instead of the correct order.

I tracked the error to the code above, I'm pretty sure that's the problem but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: class names go UpperCase in java; itemRSS is thus pretty misleading to experienced java programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code "looks" correct in the sense that you are creating one **new** item object per loop iteration (sometimes people keep adding the *same* object all the time).

The real answer here: you need more tracing (or learn how to use a debugger). Simply make sure that each any important information becomes **observable** to you.

Given your update, most likely your itemRSS class is using **static** fields? You know when all instances of a class **share** their fields; that would explain what we see here .

Comment: I know that it happens every iteration, like this: {1} -> {2,2} -> {3,3,3} -> {4,4,4,4} but I still have no idea why

Comment: And hint: enhanced debugging support is billed with "1 upvote per update" ;-)

Comment: Oh god, it was the **static** thing. I must have used the autocorrect somewhere else on the code while still programming and forgot about it!! Ridiculous... I'll get your answer verified then, thank you!!